# Setting font-size with random value using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, font-size

When returning a fixed value, font-size is changing fine:

```
$wordElement.css('font-size', function() {
    return '3vw';
});
```

But when trying to return a random value like this:

```
$wordElement.css('font-size', function() {
    return '\'' + Math.ceil((cssRandom * 3) + 1) + 'vw\'';
});
```

It does not work.
What's wrong here? And how do I set font-size to random value?

Comment: Did you try to find out what string was getting passed to the css method?

Comment: Yes, I logged the values. And they were what I expected. '2vw' , '3vw' etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove unnecessary escape and quotes surrounding `Math.ceil` call. You can use `$.now()` `.slice()` to retrieve a "random" numeric value

```js
var cssRandom = String($.now()).slice(-1);
$("div").css("font-size", function() {
   return Math.ceil((cssRandom * 3) + 1) + "vw";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>abc</div>
```

Comment: Also is there any advantage of using $.now().slice() method over Math.random() ?

Comment: @Utsav `$.now()` is jQuery alias for `new Date().getTime()`. Not certain how to determine which approach has "advantage"? Try both.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think cssRandom is javascript.
Try

```
Math.ceil((Math.random() *3 )+1)
```

Comment: Oh! no. cssRandom is just a variable. cssRandom = Math.random() .